# JSON value always undefined, even though it's not…

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I think I'm going mad.

I'm using json objects all over this project in exactly the way I am here, except this example isn't playing nice. Anyone able to see what's wrong with it?

The json object is:

`{"theurl":"http://localhost:8888/sitename/success"}`

My javascript is:

```
function startSuccess_stripe(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form){
  console.log(responseText);
  if(typeof responseText !== 'undefined'){
    console.log(responseText);
    if(responseText['stripe']){
      alert('Your card has been declined. Please try again.');
    }else{
      console.log(responseText);
      console.log('ELSE: '+responseText['theurl']);
     // window.location = responseText['redirect'];
    }
  }
};
```

As you can see it's full of console logs. The output looks like this:

```
{"theurl":"http://localhost:8888/sitename/success"} main.min.js:2
{"theurl":"http://localhost:8888/sitename/success"} main.min.js:2
{"theurl":"http://localhost:8888/sitename/success"} main.min.js:2
ELSE: undefined
```

Why is the last one undefined?? This is how I'm referencing every other json object value in the code, and haven't had any issues, I'm baffled.

EDIT: @JasonP 's suggestion was it. The header wasn't set on this particular page, so it was being treated as HTML, not json. As I'm using codeigniter the specific code missing was `$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');` as part of the controller. For others you can set the `dataType` as part of the ajax call.

Comment: You probably need to parse the JSON before using it.

Comment: First, there's no such thing as a "JSON object". JSON is a string representation of data. In javascript, you can convert a JSON string to an object. Is responseText a string? Try `var obj = JSON.parse(responseText); console.log(obj.theurl)`.

Comment: But why haven't I had to parse any of the 45 other strings in the code? Is there something specific about this string that it has an issue with, a character, or? (object, string, whatevs, it's an array, you get my meaning). Just tried running it through json parse and am getting the classic 'Unexpected U', message. So it's still undefined.

Comment: Are you specifying a `dataType` for this ajax call?

Comment: As @JasonP says, if you specify `dataType: 'json'` jQuery [will parse the data into an object automatically](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: If you're working in Chrome, `console.log()` can sometimes behave in weird ways.

Comment: @JasonP - That's it, so obvious now. It's the one controller (in my CI app) that doesn't define the header as part of the page. Doh. Cheers! Whenever else I've done this console.log wouldn't even give me the json, it would output the whole thing as undefined, so the alarm bells hadn't rung. Incidentally I haven't needed to define the type in the jquery, as that's handled by the page headers (and I'm using the jquery ajaxSubmit plugin), but that was still the core issue.

Comment: What's the etiquette @JasonP - did you want to stick that up as an answer and I'll mark it, or?